# Displaying or nesting variables within a variable: Cordova, Ionic, emailComposer

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm creating a form style mobile application using Cordova + [Ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com) (which uses AngularJS) + [emailComposer plugin](https://github.com/jcjee/email-composer).

The idea is the user fills in a few dropdowns, radio boxes etc; then hits a button which uses emailComposer to load the response data wrapped in a bit of predefined HTML to email somewhere in the phone's native email application, which the user will need to have working.

I've got a variable $scope.foo loading some HTML into the body of the email, the problem is I then need to nest the other response data (variables) into that variable. (I can't get emailComposer to accept anymore than this one variable).

The question is how do I display the $scope variables inside some HTML inside another $scope variable?

As emailComposer isn't using the AngularJS I can't continue using the {{piping}} I think.

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngStorage'])


exampleApp.controller("EmailController", function($scope) {

    $scope.someVariable = "whatever";
    $scope.anotherVariable = "something";

    $scope.foo = "<h1>I want to insert the two variables here: {{$scope.someVariable}} and here: {{$scope.anotherVariable}} in some nice HTML</h1>";

    $scope.sendEmail = function() {
        if(window.plugins && window.plugins.emailComposer) {
            window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(function(result) {
                console.log("Email Sucess");
            },
                "subject here",                         //subject line
                $scope.foo,                             //body
                ["someone@example.com", "some.else@example.com"],   //to
                null,                                   //CC
                null,                                   //BCC
                true,                                   //isHTML
                null,                                   //attachments
                null                                    //attachment data
            );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use something like var emailBody=$scope.$eval($scope.foo) and then pass the emailBody variable to your sendEmail function. That might not be 100% correct, but basically, evaluating the body and then passing the result seems like the correct approach.